# How to draw graphics to a form upon form startup

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

Im trying to draw a graphic on a form upon form startup. I've tried putting the graphic components inside the form constructer, but i cannot seem to get it working. This is what i've got so far.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
    }
```

}

Any and all help will be awesome,

Thanks guys

Comment: Use the paint event,it will render on startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a Bitmap, e.g.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
... // Draw
this.BackgroundImage = b;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to handle the `Paint` event, whereat you can draw directly to the graphics context each time the form is invalidated. e.g.

```
this.Paint += Form1_Paint;

...

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
    g.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
    g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
}
```

Comment: I cant draw it as a background image man, I've done that previously and would just prefer if i can draw directly to the form.. is there a way to do this  ?

Comment: How would i go about doing it with the Paint event? 

Can you give me an example ?

Comment: ?? why create another graphics object? e.Graphics IS the required object

Comment: That doesn't create a new object, merely a handy reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
        }
```